# refer to nth element of vector

Tags: loops, element

I would like to refer to the nth-1 entry in a vector which gets enlarged in each iteration of a loop. How do I refer to this element without having to be specific about its position in the vector?

if I put for example:

```
vector <- c(0)
T <- 100
for (time in 1:T){
  vector <- cbind(vector, sample(0:1,1))
}
```

calling up the vector gives me 100 random binary integers . So far so good.

```
vector
```

How do I print (or otherwise use) the nth-1 entry from the bottom each time the loop runs through?

Thanks in advance!

Okay, after some time I found the solution. In case anyone is interested:

```
vector <- c()
T <- 5
for (time in 1:T){
  vector <- cbind(vector, sample(-1:1,1))
  print(vector[,(length(vector)-1)])
}
```

solves the issue. It prints the last four numbers of the vector.